# Cannot get footer to bottom and not in the middle of my main body content

Tags: javascript, html, css, footer, positioning

I am very knew to coding (first time) and I have searched for 7 hours for a solution to my issue but cannot seem to get it right. I am trying to get my footer to stay below the main content on my page but cant get it right. I have messed around with positioning etc and researched other peoples answers on here but none have helped.

I have a container div and inside this is 3 more divs 'header' 'body' 'footer'. 
My code is as follows:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f0f4f6;
}


/*Global */

.container {
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*Header **/

header {
  background: #f0f4f6;
  padding-top: 20px;
  min-height: 70px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

header li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  color: #f0f4f6;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

header img {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

header nav {
  margin: 80px;
  float: right;
}

header .current a {
  color: #93d9e6;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #93d9e6;
  font-weight: bold;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}


/* Slideshow container */

div slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f0f4f6;
  margin: 100%;
  padding: 4px;
}

.slideshow-container {
  width: 95%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/*Main Body */

#boxes {
  float: left;
  align: left;
  width: 50%;
  position: static;
}

h1 {
  font: 30px arial;
  font-size: 1.875em;
}

h2 {
  font: 24px arial;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.image1 {
  float: right;
  position: static;
}

.image2 {
  float: right;
  position: static;
}

.image3 {
  float: right;
  position: static;
}


/*footer*/

footer {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #4985c5;
  text-align: left;
}

h3 {
  font: 18px arial;
  font-size: 1.3333333333333333em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h4 {
  font: 14px arial;
  font-size: 0.8750em;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background: #f0f4f6;
  padding: 10px;
}

.body {
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  /* Height of the footer */
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  /* Height of the footer */
  background: #4985c5;
}

.clearfooter {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <header>
      <div id="Logo">
        <img src="images/hike_adventure_logo.png" width="220" height="125" alt="" />
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">Sample Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">Sample Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">Sample Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div class="body">

    <body>
      <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
          <img src="images/Monument_Valley_Adventure_slider.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Monument Valley</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
          <img src="images/Mountain_Adventure_slider.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Mountain</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
          <img src="images/Skiing_Adventures_slider.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Skiing Adventure</div>
        </div>
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
      </div>
      <section id="boxes">
        <div class="hike">
          <h1>Welcome to Hike Adventures</h1>
          <h2>Safari Adventures</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae bibendum libero, et aliquet nulla. Praesent molestie, nulla rutrum accumsan blandit, nisl diam iaculis neque, at laoreet justo lacus et tortor. Curabitur a turpis id urna auctor
            finibus ut ut elit. Phasellus commodo congue tincidunt. In quis interdum urna. Etiam pharetra ante rutrum massa sodales hendrerit vel eu lacus. Proin lorem magna, faucibus placerat mi vitae, ullamcorper tincidunt dolor. Morbi aliquam nulla
            vel viverra imperdiet. Nam tempor ante vel magna condimentum convallis.</p>
        </div>
        <aside class="image1">
          <img src="images/safari_adventure_t.jpg" alt="Safari Adventures">
        </aside>
        <br>
        <div class="sky">
          <h2>Parachuting Adventures</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae bibendum libero, et aliquet nulla. Praesent molestie, nulla rutrum accumsan blandit, nisl diam iaculis neque, at laoreet justo lacus et tortor. Curabitur a turpis id urna auctor
            finibus ut ut elit. Phasellus commodo congue tincidunt. In quis interdum urna. Etiam pharetra ante rutrum massa sodales hendrerit vel eu lacus. Proin lorem magna, faucibus placerat mi vitae, ullamcorper tincidunt dolor. Morbi aliquam nulla
            vel viverra imperdiet. Nam tempor ante vel magna condimentum convallis.</p>
        </div>
        <aside class="image2">
          <img src="images/sky_adventures_t.jpg" alt="Sky Adventures">
        </aside>
        <br>
        <div class="tropical">
          <h2>Tropical Adventures</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae bibendum libero, et aliquet nulla. Praesent molestie, nulla rutrum accumsan blandit, nisl diam iaculis neque, at laoreet justo lacus et tortor. Curabitur a turpis id urna auctor
            finibus ut ut elit. Phasellus commodo congue tincidunt. In quis interdum urna. Etiam pharetra ante rutrum massa sodales hendrerit vel eu lacus. Proin lorem magna, faucibus placerat mi vitae, ullamcorper tincidunt dolor. Morbi aliquam nulla
            vel viverra imperdiet. Nam tempor ante vel magna condimentum convallis.</p>
        </div>
        <aside class="image3">
          <img src="images/tropical_adventures_t.jpg" alt="Tropical Adventures">
        </aside>
      </section>
      <br>
    </body>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfooter">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <section id="footer">
      <footer>
        <h1>Explore with us...</h1>
        <h3>Subscribe to our newsletter!</h3>
        <form>
          <input type="email" placeholder="" name="Subscribe to Newsletter...">
          <button type="submit" class="button_2" name="button">Subscribe</button>
        </form>
        <h4>Hike Adventure, Barrow Street, Carlow, Ireland</h4>
        <h4>Telephone: 059-9112345</h4>
        <h4>Email: info@hike_adventure.ie</h4>
      </footer>
    </section>
  </div>
```

any advice would be greatly appreciated. I understand some of my coding might not be perfect but as I said this is my first time trying this.

Comment: can you put your markup & css into a working snippet?

Comment: what do you mean by a working snippet? sorry

Comment: I will edit it for now but make sure to search "How to use code snippets StackOverflow" and you should have enough information to know how to use it.

Comment: I don't get your question completely, can you elaborate on your issue?

Comment: using the above code my footer is positioned in the middle of the body on my website. For example under my slideshow I have 3 paragraphs and 3 pictures. The footer is above these and the text is flowing under the footer.

Comment: you'll need to show your entire markup because currently there is **no** `body` tag within your markup.

Comment: i put it all up now. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: The footer will be at the bottom and display normally by default if you remove the `position: absolute; height: 60px;`. Absolute positioning removes an element from the default flow of the page. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xddqog

Comment: Thank you so much you have made my day!!!!! it works :)